# Find correct Com-Port with Batch file

Tags: batch-file, serial-port

I searched the web and stackoverflow but couldnt find an answer that is helpful to my question, so i decided to ask here directly.

I want to write a batch file which checks a number of COM-Ports and searches the one where an arduino is put on.

my idea was to ask each com port one after another via the `mode comX` command.

The Com Port with an Arduino on it answers like that

```
Status for device COMXX:
-----------------------
Baud:              57600
............
```

If I found the right com port the answer to that command should be compared, but I could not find a command to save the answer in a variable or directly compare the answer to the string I want to.